# Drupal 7 Ajax HTTP error, Result code 200 with Response on Localhost

Tags: php, ajax, drupal-7, xampp

I am having an Ajax error on each ajax call used in my drupal site running on my **local machine** with **xampp**. The same version of code **runs just fine on production website** so I'm having a hard time to figure out whats wrong.

Response text is returning a Json object. I tried to find a way to see the full error but with no success. How can I see full error message?

As you can see in the image

1. HTTP Result Code:200
2. Path: system/ajax
3. StatusText: OK
4. Response text is not empty

[image: Error message is attached]

Comment: You should check the error log in Drupal admin. You can find the log at admin/reports/dblog.

Comment: Nothing relevant there. When I filter by ajax it show only errors from June...

Comment: Ahh! i see its working on your production server. Its the time to check the PHP version on the local machine and both should match. This may be the issue of different PHP version.

Comment: Downgraded my php from 5.5 to 5.4 as my server hostmonster works on. No success. Get same error..

Comment: Could you confirm that your PHP version is same on both production and local server? if yes, then you need to provide more information like any url or code snippets. Also please check the list of modules on the production and local to achieve same scenario on both local and production server.

Comment: Which error do you mean ?? When the HTTP result code equals 200, That mean the request is done successfully. And i see a response in the image, Something likes an object "may be json object", Anyway, If you think that response is error or something is not familiar with that is because that response text not encoded well.  go to the file you request it with ajax and encode it in utf-8.

Comment: This problem may be due to encoding issues, is there any encoding differences between your *dev* and *prod* machines (both in the files and the database)?